# onClick not working in react class based component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following class based component:

```
class PostLike extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
            likes: null,
            like_id: null
        }
        this.likeSubmit = this.likeSubmit.bind(this)
        this.unlikeSubmit = this.unlikeSubmit.bind(this)
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/likes/post/${this.props.post.id}`)
        .then(res => this.setState({ likes: res.data.likes, like_id: res.data.like_id }))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }
    likeSubmit() {
        const data = {
            post: this.props.post.id
        }
        axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/like/', data)
        .then(res => {
            this.setState({ likes: true, like_id: res.data.id })
            this.props.setParentState({num_likes: this.props.num_likes + 1})
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }
    unlikeSubmit() {
        axios.delete(`http://10.0.1.11:8000/posts/like/${this.state.like_id}/`)
        .then(() => {
            this.setState({ likes: false, like_id: null })
            this.props.setParentState({num_likes: this.props.num_likes - 1})
            console.log('clicked')
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }
    render() {
        let button
        if (this.state.likes) {
            button = <Button onClick={this.unlikeSubmit}><FavoriteIcon /></Button>
        } else {
            button = <Button onClick={this.likeSubmit}><FavoriteBorderIcon /></Button>
        }
        return ( 
            <div>
                {button}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I have done everything right with creating a method, but the onClick isn't invoking the method. I am also using material ui, can someone please help me fix this.

UPDATE: The Button component is from material ui and has worked before, I also tried using a normal  component and it still didn't work. I also tried adding this: onClick={() => console.log('clicked')}, which correctly worked. SO it is probably an error with the method.

Comment: Please include your ``FavoriteIcon`` component in your code because your current code doesn't looks to contain any error. Also you could console any test string inside the method to check if the method is being called or not!

Comment: I am sure it must be getting called!

Comment: Well, [this](https://codepen.io/JasonGoemaat/pen/QWypegv) works, impossible to tell why yours doesn't from what is given.  Try creating a copy and strip EVERYTHING out, then build using that base and start adding things back to see when it breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure it will works with `button` instead of `Button`. Where does you Button component comes from ? If you want an onClick event on a Button component, the component should take a prop. Else, you can simply wrap you  with a div and trigger onClick on it, but that's not supposed to be like that.

Comment: The <Button> component is from material ui

Comment: Are you sure your API Call is working fine ? Does a console.log show something in the console if you write it in your method ? (Edit : Just saw your answer, good then :))

Answer (score 0):

I have found out why it doesn't work, I was sending an api request to the wrong url, I'm sorry for bothering all of you.